# How can i reference a MenuItem?

Tags: c#, contextmenu, menuitem

I am adding MenuItems to my ContextMenu like this:

```
mnuContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("Delete", DeleteFile);
```

Now i want to disable this MenuItem, like this:

```
x.Enabled = false;
```

What MenuItem reference do I have to use for x?

Comment: DeleteFile.Enabled = false

Comment: Looks like homework or interview question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have anything to directly reference it. You could get it using the indexer of the MenuItems property:

```
mnuContextMenu.MenuItems[0].Enabled = false; // if it were the first item
```

or you could have a reference when creating it:

```
var deleteMenuItem = new MenuItem("Delete", DeleteFile);
mnuContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(deleteMenuItem);
```

and then you have the reference to use later:

```
deleteMenuItem.Enabled = false;
```

You may need to store it as a private data member of your class, rather than a local variable if you're planning to use it outside of your current function.